# Supersymmetrizing bosonic actions at higher orders

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, supersymmetry, field-theory, fermions, action

1. Given only the bosonic terms of a supersymmetric action, using a knowledge of the (local) supersymmetry transformations, is there a systematic way of reconstructing the fermionic terms?
2. More generally, if higher order bosonic terms are added to the action with unknown coefficients, how can one use the knowledge of the original SUGRA transformations + the fact that the original action was supersymmetric, to compute these coefficients? I don't see how this is possible without also knowing the extra fermionic terms that these higher order bosonic terms spawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, there is systematic way called the Noether procedure. Simply you write down all possible 2-derivative fermionic terms with arbitrary coefficients and vary the action using the SUSY transformation rules. Then, you fix the coefficients to obtain the invariance up to a total derivative.
2. When you have 4-derivatives, there are two cases:

a. Off-Shell SUSY: In this case, if the theory has superconformal symmetry, then you can use superconformal tensor calculus. If not, then use off-shell superspace. In the worst case scenario, you can once again write down all possible bosonic and fermionic terms and vary the action using the off-shell transformation rules. You need to fix the arbitraray coefficients to get invariance up to a total derivative.

b. On-Shell SUSY: In this case, you have to modify the action as well as the transformation rules. This is because the on-shell supersymmetry means that the transformation rules form a closed algebra when the field equations are imposed. This one is quite tedious, and the procedure is again the Noether procedure. I do not think you want to go into this one.

Comment: Thanks @John Doe for the answer. (1) why is the 4-derivative case special? (2) By off-shell SUSY, one usually means including auxiliary terms (with suitable SUSY variations). Does the Noether procedure help here?

Suppose I have $d = 4, \mathcal{N} = 1$ supergravity, and I want to study what happens on adding terms that are higher order in the curvature, e.g. the Gauss Bonnet term $tr(R^2)$. Simply adding this (bosonic) term to the Lagrangian, how does the Noether procedure help to fix the coefficient of *this* term?

Comment: (1). There is nothing special with 4 derivative. I just mean higher derivative Lagrangians. (2) Yes, the Noether procedure definitely helps. As a matter of fact, it is most helpful when the algebra is closed independent of the field equations, thus in off-shell sugra. However, many techniques has been developed as mentioned in my previous post, and I would suggest you to use those. GB in 4D is a total derivative, and if you want to supersymmetrize that, you can just write down all possible total derivatives using the fields in the Weyl multiplet, and fix the coefficients by Noether procedure.